# Cant access grails one to many relationship data

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am asking a dump question as i am new one to grails.

I have two domain School , Classes

```
class School {
static hasMany = [ classes: Classes ]
}
```

And

```
class Classes {
static belongsTo = [School]   
}
```

Now i can not get data - like if 's' school have c1,c2,c3 classes
i check two ways to get.

```
1. classesInstanceList = Classes.findAllBySchool(s)
```

it returns null;

```
2. classesInstanceList = s.getClasses();
```

it returns follwing error message

```
Message: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.test.School.classes, no session or session was closed
```

Please someone suggest what can i do. i am stucked now . Why The first one does not work please explain someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a back reference from your `Classes` domain to school and then search by the school object.

```
class Classes {
    static belongsTo = [school:School]
    static constraints = {}
}


class School {
    static hasMany = [ classes: Classes ]
    static constraints = {}
    String toString(){"$id"}
}
```

test:

```
def s = new School()
def c = new Classes()

s.addToClasses(c)
s.save(flush:true)

println Classes.findAllBySchool(s)
```

This should give you the `classes` related to your `school`.